# A formula for periodical occurrences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We assume a guy named "A" who works for $a$ days and rests for $m$ days, and a guy named "B" who works for $b$ days and rests for $n$ days. If $a+m$ and $b+n$ are coprime, then the total period is $(a+m)(b+n)$, and in this period, the days that A and B work together are $ab$.
I verified this conclusion for $a, b, m, n$ in $[1, 10]$ and they all hold true. So I'm confident of its validity. But I really don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which says that if $a+m$ and $b+n$ are coprime, the map $$\phi: x\mapsto (x {\ \rm mod\ } (a+m), x {\ \rm mod\ }(b+n))$$ is a bijection between $$\hbox{$\{0, 1, \dots, (a+m)(b+n)-1\}$ and $\{0,\dots,a+m-1\}\times\{0,\ldots,b+n-1\}$.}$$
If the days on which A works in the period of length $a+m$ correspond to the subset $S$ of cardinality $a$ of $\{0, 1, \dots, a+m-1\}$, and the days on which B works in the period of length $b+n$ correspond to the subset $T$ of cardinality $b$ of $\{0, 1, \ldots, b+n-1\}$, then the days on which they work together in the overall cycle of length $(a+m)(b+n)$ will correspond to $\phi^{-1}(S\times T)$, which, since $\phi$ is a bijection, has cardinality $(\# S)(\# T)=ab$.